# How to create an MSMQ Failover system

Tags: msmq, failover

Our company website places orders into MSMQ, where a separate service retrieves and forwards them to our corporate order processing system. The design is dependent on the single MSMQ server always being up and running. I've been tasked with creating a redundant/failover system that will handle an MSMQ server failure. What is the best practice for doing this?

Thanks

(.Net 3.5, Windows Server 2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest from an architectural point of view is to cluster MSMQ so the service can failover from one node to another. Sender and receiver point both to the clustered queue. Is an expensive solution if you have no other clustered resources to share the hardware of.

You could have a scenario where you have several servers and send the messages multiple times, once per server (or multicast once to them all). The receiving process can use round robin to read the message. Needs some basic cleanup logic for the extra, unused messsages. So a cheaper solution but slightly more complicated.

Various possibilities; depends on budget, acceptable down-time, etc.

Comment: I have implemented the broadcast architecture in the past. It works nicely for aviailability. As you say, you need some way of only processing each message once. Or you have an idempotent process on the other end which can process the same data over and over without ill effects.